# A simple question about probability that a r.v. is less than another

Tags: probability-theory

I kept on getting an answer that I don't want, and I believe it hinges on this (really) simple question that I seem unable to verify because I am too tired...

We know that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, we have that
$$P(X \leq Y) = \int_0^\infty \int_0^y P(X=x)P(Y=y) \, dx \, dy.$$
Along the same line of thought, is it true that
$$P(X \leq CY) = \int_0^\infty \int_0^{y/c} P(X=x)P(Y=y/c) \,dx \,dy?$$
Thanks!

Comment: $P(X=x)=0$ if $X$ is a continuous random variable.

Comment: Yes, it is true. With $X$ and $Y$ independent, we have $X$ and $CY$ also independent. So, we repeat your first formula with the two new random variables and their new density/distribution functions accordingly.

Comment: @Shash: What? The first formula is nonsense. When X and Y are continuous, the RHS is always zero as pointed out by V.C.

Comment: Well, you should replace the probability terms with density functions. That should do - I was assuming that was implicit, did not bother to put it there. Also, should point out that the integral ranges have to respect the domain of the random variables. For instance, a uniform random variable between 0 and 1 should have the outer integral range as 0 to 1.

Comment: @V.C. sorry, I meant $f_X(x)$ instead of $P(X=x)$...

Comment: @Shash Thanks, turns out I was pretty close to what I wanted:
$P(X\leq CY) = \int_{x \leq cy} f_X(x)f_Y(y)\,dA = \int_0^\infty \int_0^{cy} f_X(x)f_Y(y)\,dx\,dy$.